# Unable to jquery select contents inside frame

Tags: jquery

I am unable to select anything inside of this frame. I saw a post were some people were saying it is possible.

The frame is on this page.
http://www.pcpao.org/?pg=http://www.pcpao.org/general.php?strap=163007693590010340

And look like this.

```
<frame name=bodyFrame" src="http://www.pcpao.org/general.php?strap=163007693590010340">
#document
<html>...</html>
 </frame>
```

Is this unselectable because there is an iframe in a frame?

Comment: This is by design. You cannot get access to an iframe which references an external domain.

Comment: Your must integrate your js api on http://www.pcpao.org/ )

Comment: For parsing "js  protected" sites you must simulate browser. Use some server JS language.

Comment: It is in the same domain, I saw it. That's simply amazing @William how you are trying to access in jQuery? From **noname** to **bodyFrame**?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
var t = window.frames['bodyFrame'].document.body
```